# Nao cachear uma View usando Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um *popup* que faz a renderização de outra `View` usando o `RenderPartial()`.

```
@Html.DevExpress().PopupControl(
    settings =>
    {
      settings.Name = "pcModalMode";

      settings.Width = 550;
      settings.Height = 420;

      settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "SearchEditButton", Action = "PopupPartialFilter" };
      settings.AllowDragging = true;
      settings.HeaderText = Resources.Resources.Pesquisar;
      settings.CloseAction = CloseAction.OuterMouseClick;
      settings.PopupAnimationType = AnimationType.None;
      settings.CloseOnEscape = true;
      settings.Modal = true;
      settings.PopupHorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.WindowCenter;
      settings.PopupVerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.WindowCenter;
      settings.SetContent(() =>
      {
        Html.RenderPartial("_PartialScriptsGridView");
      });
      settings.ClientSideEvents.CloseUp = "function(s, e){ pcModalMode.Hide();}";
      settings.ClientSideEvents.EndCallback = "function(s, e){ pcModalMode.Show(); }";
      settings.ClientSideEvents.Shown = "function(s,e){s.PerformCallback();}";

    }).GetHtml()
```

O problema é que nesta `View` que é renderizada, possui métodos `javascript` onde uso o `Razor` para imprimir métodos diferentes de acordo com os dados passados no model:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.UseValueChangedEvent) && Model.UseValueChangedEvent.Equals("S")) {
  @Model.ControlName<text>_ValueChanged(cmb, null)</text>
}
```

Isso está sendo cacheado, fazendo com que toda vez que navegue para outra tela o meu *popup* venha com o código cacheado.

Teria como toda vez que eu passar para outra tela eu renderizar a partial novamente com os valores enviados no model?

Comment: Mas o cache está vindo do browser ou do servidor? Tente usar o atributo OutputCache na sua action que renderiza sua partial. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

Comment: Você tem certeza que você precisa do razor para imprimir esses métodos diferentes? Aliás... que você deveria ter métodos diferentes? onde está o javascript? Apresente também uma versão rederizada da view.